# How to calculate gap between 2 time stamps in Athena (Presto)?

Tags: sql, aggregate, presto, amazon-athena

I Have many IOT devices that sends data to my Amazon Athena server, i created a table to store the data and the table contains 2 columns: LocalTime indicate the time that the IOT device captured his status, ServerTime indicate the time the Data arrived to the server (sometimes the IOT device doesn't have network connections )

I would like to count the "gaps" in block of hours (let's say 1 hour ) for a period of last week,  in order to know the deviation of the data arriving, for example:

[image]

the result should be like 
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date_diff()`:

```
select date_diff(hour, servertime, servertime) as hours,
       count(*)
from t
group by date_diff(hour, servertime, servertime)
order by hours;
```

This doesn't return the `0` values.  For that, a `left join` can be used:

```
select v.hours, count(*)
from (values (0), (1), (2), (3)) v(hours) left join
     t
     on hours = date_diff(hour, servertime, servertime)
group by v.hours
order by hours;
```